# Oracle DB - Flashback functionality

Tags: oracle, flashback

I have recently joined a Team where they execute their DB Changes bundled in a sql scripts. For Prod Readiness - They refresh Databases in multiple environments. Pick up 1 env, say Test1, execute sql scripts and if it fails, fix the errors in script. Now Pick up another Env, say Test2, run it here and keep going on until it all succeeds i.e. spool is all clean!
Can we not restrict it all to just 1 environment by creating a Restore Point before script execution and using Flashback after execution, and do it on repeat until the spool comes clean? Am I missing something? Any drawbacks of using Flashback?
Any alternatives or other considerations to use Flashback?

Comment: Any functionality introduced in enterprise software exist for the reason. It always have benefits and drawbacks, but it is very hard to tell what is drawback for your particular case and what is not. Answers for this question tends to be opinion based and this type of question is discouraged. You may check all the requirements for flashback to work in the [Backup and Recovery User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/using-flasback-database-restore-points.html#GUID-909BBEEF-389B-443B-8CD7-F3C027AAFFF3)